# R - error in summarise_impl (.data, dots) : Column `cSR` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2

Tags: r

I am trying to group some data and summarise, but I get this error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `cSR` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2
```

A sample of my HData looks like so:

```
H hW hS  hTDW  hTDS hTCW hTDS
1  3  7   6    10    3   10
2  6  10  1    3     2   6
3  2  7   1    3     1   5
```

My desired output is like this:

```
H cSR   tSR  dSR
1  43%  60%  30%
2  60%  33%  33%
3  29%  33%  20%
```

I have so far tried to do this with the following:

```
pastPerfS = group_by(HData, FNAME, H)
pastPerfS = summarise(pastPerfS, cSR = round((hW/hS*100),2), tSR = round((hTDW/hTDS*100),2), dSR = round((hTCW/hTCS*100),2))
```

But it results in the above error.

Comment: I have added in some details to the original post. If anyone has any ideas as to why this isn't working, it would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a short example of your data it is hard to provide a fully solution. Next time, try to include the table's head.

However given your code, you can try using `dplyr` package something like:

```
pastPerfS %>% group_by(HData, FNAME, H) %>%
              dplyr::summarize(cSR = round((hW/hS*100),2), 
                               tSR = round((hTDW/hTDS*100),2), 
                               dSR = round((hTCW/hTCS*100),2)) %>%
              as.data.frame()
```

Comment: this is great, thank you for your response. This has helped solve my problem.